# How to iterate visible dhtmlx treeview items?

Tags: filter, treeview, dhtmlx

I have filtered Dhtmlx treeview (with checkbox) in client side and now the filtered items are visible.
For Ex: I have 100 items (node) in treeview, after filtered we have only 15 items are visible.
Question: Now i have to selectAll / UnselectAll for the visible 15 items only. How to iterate dhtmlx visible treeview?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such logic in the treeview.
Also, could you please, provide your using logic for the filtering, as also there is no inbuilt logic for the filtering in the treeview.